# Where are all the Netbeans plugins?

Tags: plugins, netbeans

I was a Netbeans user several years ago, about the time that Apache acquired it and was in the process of transitioning the website. Soon after that I switched to Eclipse, nothing against Netbeans, I just found Eclipse "better" at the time. Now I'd like to give Netbeans another try but it seems that Netbeans has little to no support. Everything I find in a search for plugins wants to take me to plugins.netbeans.org, but that site won't load. Apache's Netbeans plugins "catalog" lists all of 55 plugins. 55! Anybody else having this kind of problem?

Originally, I hoped to find a dark theme, but I did find the Look and Feel settings as mentioned by @WillShackleford (thanks, by the way). But I would still like to know where the hundreds of cool plugins are that used to be out there. Anybody have a link that works?

Comment: From [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask): _"To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions where …your question is just a rant in disguise: “______ sucks, am I right?”..."_.

Comment: Also see  [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for specific advice on how to improve your question.

Comment: I googled "apache netbeans plugin" and https://plugins.netbeans.apache.org/ was the first result.  However if all you want is a dark theme no plugin is necessary. Tools -> Options -> Appearance -> Look and Feel  and choose one of the dark ones like FlatLaf Dark.

Comment: Yes, thank you WillShackleford, that's very helpful. I also edited my question to better indicate what I'm after, that being what happened to the hundreds of Netbeans plugs that used to be out there?